# Splitting string into numbers and text

Tags: javascript, string

I have string that look like 
`Temperature is 125` or `Temperature is 4`

The strings are always the same format, that is, the number always occurrs at the end of the string.

I need to get split these strings where the numbers occur so I will be left with two strings, for example

```
string1 = Temperature is
string2 = 125
```

Any ideas how I would do this?

Comment: Extract the substring with `.substr`.

Comment: the number at the end can be of variable length. and so can the 'Temperature is' text at the start. It won't always be 'Temperature is'

Answer (score 5):

Using a regex:

```
var matches = "Temperature is 125".match(/^(.*) (\d+)$/);
console.log(matches[1]); // Temperature is
console.log(matches[2]); // 125
```

Comment: One other thing. There may be brackets around the number at the end. Sometimes it looks like (125), sometimes its just 125. Any ideas how to handle this, I still need to get the text (before the brackes) and the number at the end?

Comment: Personally I think the regex should be **/^(.*)(\d+)$/** as the whitespace may or may not occur ;-)

Comment: @oodavid that would eat all the digits up to last one.

Comment: @John McDonald `^(.*) \(?(\d+)\)?$` might be an option

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple method for you.

```
var text = "Temperature is (125)";
var result = text.lastIndexOf(" ");
var number = text.substring(result,text.length);
var textBody = text.substring(0,result);
```

Just check whether you can use this. You have to assume that always the number (with or without brackets) comes as the last word.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If the item at the end is simply the item after the last space in the string, you can use .lastIndexOf, like

```
var s='Some text part   1234';
var splitAt = s.lastIndexOf(' ');
document.write('Text = &quot;' + s.substring(0, splitAt) + '&quot;<br />Number = &quot;' + s.substring(splitAt+1) + '&quot;');
```

Comment: Ah, Prasad beat me to it while I was figuring how to post code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the String is always `Temperature is XX`, you could do

```
var str1 = theString.substr(0, 14);
var str2 = theString.substr(15);
```

EDIT: Whoops, this is a javacript question, not Java

Comment: If you're going to use magic numbers, might as well just have magic strings and put in `"Temperature is"`.

Comment: It won't always be 'Temperature is'. It will always be some text followed by a number.

Comment: @JohnMcDonald: See, this is information we need to know at the BEGINNING

Comment: @JohnMcDonald, indeed. Your question is poorly worded, I quote: "The strings are always the same format", and then in a comment you wrote the *exact* opposite.

Comment: yeah, i worded it badly, sorry about that.